# Best datastructure for mobx + react-virtualized list

Tags: mobx, react-virtualized

I have a few thousand items in a mobx store, kept in an `observable.map()` data structure, as uuid: model pairs. Model is a class with @observable properties. I choose `map()` as a datastructure as I need to:

- add items
- remove items
- check if item is present in the store

in reasonable performance and `map()` offered these properties.

I'd like to render this list in a react-virtualized `List` view, which however requires an array-like datastructure. I'd also like to keep the order in the list consistent: adding or removing an item should not shuffle the view.

What is the best choice for the above problem? Using a `@computed` on `.values()` and `.size` to on-the-fly transform the map into a list like structure? Or should I be using a totally different data structure? Is it possible to use react-virtualized's List directly with a `map()` like input?

Comment: I think it's hard to say if `map` will be a good/bad choice in all cases. Have you tried and checked if a large list doesn't ruin the experience in your particular case? If the list is more important than add/remove/check speed, you could change to an observable array and use e.g. `array.find(e => e.id === id);` instead of an index in a map.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I changed to `observable.array()` and the add/remove performance is actually better this way. Find is only used occasionally, and a simple `array.indexOf(e)` works well, without the need to use any kind of id.